# Xamarin GetButton for AlertDialog from DialogFragment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I'm working to get a Dialog box with input text. I found a sample that create the AlertDialog extending a DialogFragment.

```
class RequestPinDialog : DialogFragment
```

I would like to disable the Positive Button until the input text is filled with something.
So after the Show I try to call the GetButton but my return dialog is of my custom type and not of type AlertDialog so the GetButton doesn't exists.
Is not possibile to cast my custom dialog to alertdialog.
So I guess that I need to expose the inner dialog to access the button.
Is it correct? There is a simple way to disable confirm button until something fills the Edit Text?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to expose the button per se, you can just create a method in your `RequestPinDialog` class that do the job you want.

```
RequestPinDialog.EnablePositeButton(true);
```

And this method will have access to the positive button.

Or you can do all the logic inside the `RequestPinDialog` as both the EditText and the Button are part of it.

You'd just need to attach to the AfterTextChanged event of the EditText and Enable/Disable the Positive Button based on the text length, this way all logic will be kept in the class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried but the Positive Button is not disabled :-( I can't figure why.

Comment: How and where are you disabling it?

Comment: After some study and serach, I try to disable it after `dialog.show()`. During `OnCreate` event of the dialog the `PositiveButton` is `null`.